# mongoose - perform query while excluding certain records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of records that I normally want all results for, however in some cases the user will provide a list of IDs to exclude from the results.

Is there a way to perform a query with mongoose, and give it an array of IDs to exclude from the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it is as easy as this:

```
db.coll.find( { "_id": { "$nin": [ 1, 2, 3 ] } } )
```

In Mongoose it would be:

```
Model.where( "_id" ).nin( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian (and for adding the mongo version), this works!

Comment: err, mongoose version. :)